# Compactly induced representations and the Whittaker model

Tags: rt.representation-theory, p-adic-groups

Let $G$ be the group $GL_n(F)$, where $F$ is a non-archimedean locally compact field. Let us fix a character $\psi$ of $(F,+)$ which is trivial on $\mathcal{P}_{F}$ and non-trivial on $\mathcal{O}_{F}$ ($\mathcal{O}_{F}$ is the ring of integers of $F$ and $\mathcal{P}_{F}$ is the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{F}$) and define a character $\theta_{\psi}$ of the group $U$ of upper-triangular matrices with $1$ on the diagonal by
$$\displaystyle\theta_{\psi}((u_{i,j})_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n})=\psi(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}u_{i,i+1}).$$
An irreducible smooth representation $(\pi,V)$ of $G$ is called generic if the intertwining space $\rm{Hom}_G(\pi,{\rm Ind}_{U}^{G}\theta_{\psi})$ is nonzero. J.Bernstein and A.Zelevinski proves that for an irreducible and admissible representation of $G$ the dimension of the intertwining space $\rm{Hom}_G(\pi,{\rm Ind}_{U}^{G}\theta_{\psi})$ is at most one. In particular, an irreducible generic representation $(\pi,V)$ of $G$ is isomorphic to a unique subrepresentation of ${\rm Ind}_{U}^{G}\theta_{\psi}$ called the Whittaker model of $\pi$.

My question is : Does the compactly induced representation $\hbox{$c$-ind}_{N}^{G}1_{N}$, where $N=N_G(T)$ is the normalizer in $G$ of the diagonal torus $T$, embeds in ${\rm Ind}_{U}^{G}\theta_{\psi}$ ?

Comment: Is there a reason you are interested in $\hbox{$c$-ind}_{N}^{G}1_{N}$?